Can`t authorize using WS-Federation and ASP.NET
I have a problem with WS-Federation auth. So, there are my settings:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddWsFederation(options =>
{
    options.Wtrealm = "https://dev-archive-console-admin.eisnot.ru/";
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://my-adfs.ru/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml";
})
.AddCookie();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Publisher", policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "dev_eis_archive_admin_publisher")
    );
});

[Authorize(Policy = "Publisher")]
public class QueueController : Controller
{

So, i see adfs login page and after i try to login i see error adfs page. I`ve got logs and there: Error : MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '1' seconds
After this i added responce and request logger and now i see this: 
So, as i see - there is no claim, but i get token in my request body from ADFS and by this reason a have a redirect authorization loop.
Any ideas how to fix it?
